# GUID based RoleProvider for MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, roleprovider

I working on a MVC4 intranet application. It uses Active Directory as MembershipProvider.
But I have implemented my own RoleProvider. Its working fine.

But all role lookup methods are username  based. I would like to use the objectGUID  from the AD insted of a "simple" username.

Anyone know if/how this can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

I created a GuidRoleProvider library you can feel free to use as an example.

https://github.com/cavvon/GuidRoleProvider